# Using SQL(ite) how do I find the lowest unique child for each parent in a one to many relationship during a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables with a many to one relationship which represent *lots* and *bids* within an auction system. Each lot can have zero or more bids associated with it. Each bid is associated with exactly one lot.

My table structure (with irrelevant fields removed) looks something like this:

[image: table structure]

For one type of auction the winning bid is the **lowest unique bid for a given lot**.

E.g. if there are four bids for a given lot: [1, 1, 2, 4] the lowest unique bid is 2 (*not* 1).

So far I have been able to construct a query which will find the lowest unique bid for a single specific lot (assuming the lot ID is `123`):

```
SELECT id, value FROM bid
WHERE lot = 123 
AND amount = (
    SELECT value FROM bid 
    WHERE lot = 123
    GROUP BY value HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 
    ORDER BY value
)
```

This works as I would expect (although I'm not sure it's the most graceful approach).

I would now like to construct a query which will get the lowest unique bids for *all* lots at once. Essentially I want to perform a `JOIN` on the two tables where one column is the result of something similar to the above query. I'm at a loss as to how to use the same approach for finding the lowest unique bid in a `JOIN` though.

Am I on the wrong track with this approach to finding the lowest unique bid? Is there another way I can achieve the same result?

Can anyone help me expand this query into a `JOIN`?

Is this even possible in SQL or will I have to do it in my application proper?

Thanks in advance.

(I am using SQLite 3.5.9 as found in Android 2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by with a "having" condition to find the set of bids without duplicate amounts for each lot.

```
          select lotname, amt
          from lot inner join bid on lot.id = bid.lotid
          group by lotname, amt having count(*) = 1
```

You can in turn make that query an inline view and select the lowest bid from it for each lot.

```
select lotname, min(amt)
from
(
  select lotname, amt
          from lot inner join bid on lot.id = bid.lotid
          group by lotname, amt having count(*) = 1
) as X

group by X.lotname
```

EDIT: Here's how to get the bid id using this approach, using nested inline views:

```
 select bid.id as WinningBidId, Y.lotname,  bid.amt
from
bid
join
(   
   select x.lotid, lotname, min(amt) as TheMinAmt
from
(
    select lot.id as lotid, lotname,  amt 
    from lot inner  join bid   on lot.id = bid.lotid
    group by lot.id, lotname, amt
    having count(*)=1 
) as X

group by x.lotid, x.lotname
) as Y
on Y.lotid = bid.lotid and Y.TheMinAmt = Bid.amt
```

Comment: Whether this solution is useful, depends on whether you need the id of the bid too. No downvote from me, but the example in the question also returns the bid id.

Comment: Thank-you Tim, this query works nicely and is straightforward to understand. I am accepting this answer as I feel it is the best solution to the specific problem outlined in the question (needing the bid ID is not strictly necessary). However, in my actual application this particular problem is part of a much larger and more complex query so I may end up using Jacco's solution instead - as both work equally well - this will depend on factors beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: One could return the lot.id in the inline view (group by lot.id, lotname) and then turn the full query I provided above into an inline view (so you'd have a nested inline view), and then you could join against that inline to the bids table in order to get the bid.id  (from MyInlineView inner join bid on bid.lotid = MyInlineView.lotid and MyInlineView.TheMinAmt = bid.amt). You need to supply ... min(amt) ...  with a column alias in order to reference it. I am pleased with SQLite performance with inline views, BTW; with the proper indexes the optimizer handles them well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some subqueries to get to your desired data:

```
SELECT [b].[id] AS [BidID], [l].[id] AS [LotID], 
   [l].[Name] AS [Lot], [b].[value] AS [BidValue]
FROM [bid] [b]
INNER JOIN [lot] [l] ON [b].[lot] = [l].[id]
WHERE [b].[id] = 
   (SELECT TOP 1 [min].[id] 
    FROM [bid] [min] 
    WHERE [min].[lot] = [b].[lot]
        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                       FROM [bid] [check] 
                       WHERE [check].[lot] = [min].[lot] 
                           AND [check].[value] = [min].[value] 
                           AND [check].[id] <> [min].[id])
    ORDER BY [min].[value] ASC)
```

The most inner query (within the exists) checks if there are no other bids on that lot, having the same value.
The query in the middle (top 1) determines the minimum bid of all unique bids on that lot.
The outer query makes this happen for all lots, that have bids.

Comment: Thank-you Jacco - this query (once modified to swap TOP for LIMIT as SQLite does not support TOP) works nicely. I have accepted Tim's answer rather than yours for reasons I have explained in a comment on that answer. I do agree that your solution works, and if I could accept both answers I would.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lot.name, ( SELECT MIN(bid.value) FROM bid Where bid.lot = lot.ID) AS MinBid
FROM Lot INNER JOIN
    bid on lot.ID = bid.ID
```

If I understand you correctly this will give you everylot and their smallest bid

Comment: This will indeed give me the lowest bid for each lot. However I require the lowest *unique* bid. I.e. if there are four bids of [1, 1, 2, 4] the lowest unique bid is 2 (not 1).

Comment: @Chris Harcourt Ok, sorry, was late :-), I think Tim's answer will suit you best then.